# Element(name) returns null

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<envelope xmlns="myNamespace">
  <response code="123" />
</envelope>
```

and I want to select the `<response>` element like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(myXmlString);
XElement response = doc.Root.Element("response");
```

but it returns `null`. I know the element is there, because `doc.Root.FirstNode` is the element I need.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried rhe `Descendants()` method ?

Comment: BTW - that XML is not valid, you're missing `?` at the end, i.e. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to include the namespace to get the element:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(myXmlString);
XNamespace ns = "myNamespace";
XElement response = doc.Root.Element(ns + "response");
```

alternatively, you can use the `LocalName` to get around using the namespace:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement response = doc.Descendants().First(x => x.Name.LocalName == "response");
```

Comment: You can also use `XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I didn't know that, thanks!